# Is it possible to find out what type of neural network by the program code? Can anyone help me? I'll share the code

Tags: python

This neural network solves the problem of multiclass classification. The input is a data set that contains 61 parameters. The neural network must process this data set and implement a multiclass classification.

**creating train, validation and test sets:**

```
train_df, val_df = train_test_split(dataset, shuffle = True,
                                                    test_size = 0.3,
                                                    random_state = seed)

val_df, test_df = train_test_split(val_df, shuffle = True,
                                                    test_size = 0.00005,
                                                    random_state = seed)
```

**reducing the dominant class' number of samples:**

```
temp_df = train_df[train_df["Label"] == 0]
temp_df = temp_df.sample(n=train_df["Label"].value_counts()[3])
train_df = train_df[train_df["Label"] != 0]
train_df = pd.concat([train_df, temp_df])

class Dataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, df):
        super().__init__()
        self.df_data = torch.from_numpy(df.drop("Label", axis = 1).values)
        self.df_labels = torch.from_numpy(df["Label"].values)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.df_data)

    def __getitem__(self, index):        
        sample, label = self.df_data[index], self.df_labels[index]

        return sample, label

train_dataset, val_dataset, test_dataset = Dataset(train_df), Dataset(val_df), Dataset(test_df)


batch_size = 64
learning_rate = 0.00005
epochs = 50
```

**balanced class sampler upsamples everything to the dominant class' sample number
it increases training time, for that reason some dominant class' samples were removed**

```
train_dataloader = DataLoader(
            train_dataset,
            sampler=BalanceClassSampler(labels = train_df["Label"].values, mode = "upsampling"),
            batch_size = batch_size)

valid_dataloader = DataLoader(
            val_dataset,
            sampler = SequentialSampler(val_dataset),
            batch_size = batch_size)

test_dataloader = DataLoader(
            test_dataset,
            sampler = SequentialSampler(test_dataset),
            batch_size = batch_size)


class Net(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, input_size = 71, output_size = 15): #94 #14 #len(dataset.columns)-1
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, 512) #512
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 1024) #512
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(1024, 2048)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(2048, 2048)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(2048, 1024)
        self.fc6 = nn.Linear(1024, 512)
        self.fc7 = nn.Linear(512, output_size) #fc7
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.1)   
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.dropout(F.relu(self.fc2(x)))
        x = self.dropout(F.relu(self.fc3(x)))
        x = self.dropout(F.relu(self.fc4(x)))
        x = self.dropout(F.relu(self.fc5(x)))
        x = self.dropout(F.relu(self.fc6(x)))
        x = self.fc7(x)
        return x


net = Net().to(device)
```

**training loop**

```
loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.AdamW(net.parameters(), lr = learning_rate, weight_decay = 0.999, betas = (0.9, 0.999))

def training_loop(epochs = epochs, net = net):
    best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(net.state_dict())
    best_loss = 100
    
    for epoch in (range(epochs)):
        print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}')
        train_losses, train_accuracies = train(net)        
        val_losses, val_accuracies = validate(net)        
        print(f'Training accuracy:   {sum(train_accuracies)/len(train_accuracies)} | Training loss: {sum(train_losses)/len(train_losses)}')
        print(f'Validation accuracy: {sum(val_accuracies)/len(val_accuracies)} | Validation loss: {sum(val_losses)/len(val_losses)}')
        
        epoch_val_loss = sum(val_losses)/len(val_losses)
        
        if best_loss > epoch_val_loss:    
            best_loss = epoch_val_loss
            best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(net.state_dict())
            torch.save(net.state_dict(), 'best.pth')
            print('saving with loss of {}'.format(epoch_val_loss), 'improved over previous {}'.format(best_loss))


 def fwd_pass(X, y, step, train = False):           
    outputs = net(X)
    matches = [torch.argmax(i) == j for i, j in zip(outputs,y)]        
    acc = matches.count(True)/len(matches)
    loss = loss_function(outputs, y)
    if train:
        loss.backward()        
        optimizer.step()        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
    return acc, loss

def train(net):
    net.train()
    train_losses = []
    train_accuracies = []
    print("Training")
    for step, batch in (enumerate(train_dataloader)):
        inputs = batch[0].to(device).float()
        labels = batch[1].to(device).long()    
        acc, loss = fwd_pass(inputs, labels, step, train = True)
        if step > 0 and step % 500 == 0:            
            print(f"Step {step} of {len(train_dataloader)}, Accuracy: {sum(train_accuracies)/len(train_accuracies)}, Loss: {sum(train_losses)/len(train_losses)}")
               
        train_losses.append(loss)
        train_accuracies.append(acc)
    return train_losses, train_accuracies               
                
def validate(net):    
    net.eval()
    val_losses = []
    val_accuracies = []
    print("Validation")
    for step, batch in enumerate(valid_dataloader):            
        valid_inputs = batch[0].to(device).float()
        valid_labels = batch[1].to(device).long()
    with torch.no_grad():
        val_acc, val_loss =  fwd_pass(valid_inputs, valid_labels, step, train = False)
        
        val_losses.append(val_loss)
        val_accuracies.append(val_acc)        
    return val_losses, val_accuracies
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model Type:**
If you are asking about the type of network, based on its architecture provided in class Net, This is a Multi-layer perception(MLP) network (or multi-layer feedforward model) and can be called Artificial Neural Network (ANN), as all layers are fully connected (fc). Since depth is >=3, then it is a subset of Deep Neural Networks (DNN). In the count of layers, dropouts are not counted as separate layers.

I mentioned a couple of names in the above paragraph, and in the literature, these names are used interchangeably for such networks.

**Model Depth:**
In terms of its depth, it is 6 (we don't count input layer); you can refer to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuVdi.png) for more info

Comment: Thank you very much! You are the best. Sorry, is it possible to understand what kind of learning algorithm is used in this neural network?
Backpropagation...?

Comment: your question is not clear to me, but it is based on your train loop it is training with backpropagation ( almost all neural nets use this approach) your optimizer and loss function is defined at the first two lines of the training loop section `Cross entropy loss` as it is a multi-class problem and you are using `adamW` as optimizer.